# normalize.css vs reset.css

Tags: html, css

В чём отличия между [normalize.css](http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/) и [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). В первой ссылке есть небольшое обсуждение на эту тему. Но не делается никаких выводов. Я бы хотел понять, какие следствия возникают на практике. Сходу мне показалось, что normalize.css подходит для тех случаев, когда не нужна очень-очень сильная кастомизация. reset.css нужен, когда требует сильная кастомизация.

Пожалуйста, расскажите подробнее про за и против относительно использования данных стилей.

Comment: они делают одно и тоже различия только в том что они некоторые css штуки чуть по разному стилизуют вот и всё но мы всегда можем изобрести свой велосипед - а можем подключить какой не будь materialize и радоваться жизни

Comment: @MaximLensky можно так легко взять и удалить комменты без ведома автора?

Comment: Не использую ни то, ни другое, ибо не вижу смысла. Тех проблем, которые они решают, лично я ни разу в жизни не испытывал

Comment: я ни чего не удалял - у меня прав таких нету